# The MVP Pattern with presentation model

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp, webformsmvp

I have some questions about the MVC pattern and i am looking for feedback for what i have made.

After watching a course about the MVP pattern i started to rebuild an excercise program to this pattern. I came across some problems and question while i was at it.

1. Why do people use the interface in the pattern? I saw it sometimes in the MVC pattern and felt it wasn't always necessary but it seems almost anyone uses it.
2. How exactly do i fill the DataGridView in this case?

And this is what i made:

Model:

```
  public class PrinterModel
{

    public string printerSearch;
    public string printerCode;
    public string printer;
    public string printerType;
    public DataTable printers;

    public PrinterModel()
    {
    }
}
```

Query Class:

```
 public class Querys
{
    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
    string connectionString = @"CORRECT CONNECTION STRING";

    //Fills the DataTable with data
    public DataTable DBFillTable()
    {

        using (MySqlConnection sqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PrinterTypes", sqlCon);
            MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);


            sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
            return dtbl;
        }
    }
    // Searches for printer Type
    public DataTable SearchPrinterType(string search)
    {

        DataTable dtbl2 = new DataTable();
        if (search != "")
        {
            try
            {
                dtbl2 = dtbl.Select("PrinterType LIKE '%" + search + "%'").CopyToDataTable();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        else if (search == "")
        {
            dtbl2 = dtbl;
        }
        return dtbl2;
    }

    /* Searches for the Printer Code. */
    public string SearchPrinterCode(string search)
    {
        string result = null;

        try
        {
            var filteredRow = dtbl.Select("PrinterCode = '" + search + "'");
            result = filteredRow[0][0].ToString() + " " + filteredRow[0][1].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

CopyPrinterView:

```
 public partial class CopyPrinterView : MetroUserControl
{
    private PrinterModel printer;

    public CopyPrinterView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string PrinterSearch
    {
        get { return TxtSearchResult.Text; }
        set { TxtSearchResult.Text = value; }
    }

    public string PrinterCode
    {
        get { return TxtPrinterCode.Text; }
        set { TxtPrinterCode.Text = value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler CopyPrinter
    {
        add { BtnCopyPrinterCode.Click += value; }
        remove { BtnCopyPrinterCode.Click -= value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler TxtPrinterCodeChanged
    {
        add { TxtPrinterCode.TextChanged += value; }
        remove { TxtPrinterCode.TextChanged -= value; }
    }

}
```

SearchView:

```
 public partial class SearchView : MetroUserControl
{
    private PrinterModel printer;
    public SearchView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public string PrinterType
    {
        get { return TxtPrinterType.Text; }
        set { TxtPrinterType.Text = value; }
    }

    public event DataGridViewCellEventHandler DvgDoubleClick
    {
        add { DvgPrinters.CellDoubleClick += value; }
        remove { DvgPrinters.CellDoubleClick -= value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler TxtPrinterTypeResultChanged
    {
        add { TxtPrinterType.TextChanged += value; }
        remove { TxtPrinterType.TextChanged -= value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler LoadDvg
    {
        add { Load += value; }
        remove { Load -= value; }
    }
}
```

CopyPrinterPresenter:

```
 public class CopyPrinterPresenter
{
    private CopyPrinterView copyPrinterView;
    private PrinterModel printer;
    private Querys query;
    public CopyPrinterPresenter(CopyPrinterView copyPrinterView, PrinterModel printer, Querys query)
    {
        this.copyPrinterView = copyPrinterView;
        this.printer = printer;
        this.query = query;
        copyPrinterView.TxtPrinterCodeChanged += TxtPrinterCode_TextChanged;
        copyPrinterView.CopyPrinter += BtnCopyPrinterCode_Click;
        copyPrinterView.PrinterCode += printer.printerCode;
        copyPrinterView.PrinterSearch += printer.printerSearch;
    }

    private void BtnCopyPrinterCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (printer.printerSearch != "")
        {
            // Copy printer to clipboard if there is a result in TxtSearchResult.Text
            Clipboard.SetText(printer.printerSearch);
            string message = "Copied the printer of printer code: " + printer.printerCode;
            MetroMessageBox.Show(copyPrinterView, message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            string message = "Fill in a Printer Code";
            MetroMessageBox.Show(copyPrinterView, message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void TxtPrinterCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        printer.printerSearch = query.SearchPrinterCode(printer.printerCode);

    }
}
```

SearchPresenter:

```
 public class SearchPresenter
{
    private SearchView searchView;
    private PrinterModel printer;
    private Querys query;

    public SearchPresenter(SearchView searchView, PrinterModel printer, Querys query)
    {
        this.searchView = searchView;
        this.printer = printer;
        this.query = query;
        searchView.Load += SearchView_Load;
        searchView.TxtPrinterTypeResultChanged += TxtPrinterType_TextChanged;
        searchView.DvgDoubleClick += DvgPrinters_CellDoubleClick;
        searchView.PrinterType += printer.printerType;
    }

    private void SearchView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Initial load
        printer.printers = query.DBFillTable();
        searchView.DvgPrinters.DataSource = printer.printers;
    }

    private void TxtPrinterType_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Displays result of the query into the DataGridView
        printer.printers = query.SearchPrinterType(printer.printerType);
    }

    private void DvgPrinters_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // Copies the printercode to the clipboard of the selected cell in the row.
        if (printer.printers.Rows[e.RowIndex] != null)
        {
            //printer.printers.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["PrinterCode"].Value.ToString()
            Clipboard.SetText(printer.printers.Rows[e.RowIndex][2].ToString());
            string message = "Copied the Printer Code of the selected row";
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }
    }
}
```

MainForm:

```
 public partial class MainMetroFormCopy : MetroForm
{
    Querys query = new Querys();
    PrinterModel printer = new PrinterModel();
    public MainMetroFormCopy()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var searchViewPresenter = new SearchPresenter(searchView1,printer, query);
        var copyPrinterViewPresenter = new CopyPrinterPresenter(copyPrinterView1,printer ,query);
    }

    private void MainMetroForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```